# How do I choose the desired icon when fetching results?

Tags: php, performance, if-statement

I'm creating a Q&A website, Something like SO. Now I need to print a "check" **icon** *(to specify accepted answer)* next to every answer. Now there is some condition:

- Current user is logged?
- Current user is author of the question?
- Is there any accepted answer?

And some other cases ..!

---

Actually I implemented that. But I did it using a lot of nested `if`-statement and seems to me really unopptimized. Now I want to know is there any better algorithm to write this code?

```
$results = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       // Fetching all answers

foreach ($results as $result){

    if ($_SESSION['id'] == $author_id){            // User is logged
        if($result['id'] == $AcceptedAnswerId){    // There is accepted answer
            $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<a href='#'>
                                    <i style='color: green;' class='fa fa-check'></i>
                                 </a>";
        } else {                                   // There isn't accepted answer
            $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<a href='#'>
                                    <i style='color: gray' class='fa fa-check'></i>
                                 </a>";
        }
    } 

    elseif ($_SESSION['id'] !== $author_id) {      // User isn't logged
        if($result['id'] == $AcceptedAnswerId){    // There isn accepted answer
            $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<i style='color: green;' class='fa fa-check'></i>";
        } else {                                   // There isn't accepted answer
            $AcceptAnswerIcon = null;
        }
    }

    else {
        $AcceptAnswerIcon = null;
    }


// ... I will use $AcceptAnswerIcon in here and mix it with answer structure


} // End of "foreach" block
```

Comment: Try to write self-explanatory business-logic methods: `function userCanAcceptAnswer($user, $answer) { return $user['id'] == $answer['author_id'] && ...; }` – `if (userCanAcceptAnswer(..)) echo '<i ..';`. That should greatly simplify such template code.

Comment: @deceze That's not a valid close reason. This has been pointed out often enough before. It's too broad here and may be a good candidate for Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

First since you're only looking for 1 correct answer, after it is found (or not), it will jump out of the loop, keeping it simple:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
  $foundCorrectAnswer = ($result['id'] == $AcceptedAnswerId);
  if($foundCorrectAnswer)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

And after all, there are 3 possible outputs (the wrong thing on my first was that i only saw 2), so here it is:

```
if($isLogged)
{
  $color = $foundCorrectAnswer ? 'green' : 'gray';
  $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<a href='#'><i style='color: {$color};' class='fa fa-check'></i></a>";
}
else if($foundCorrectAnswer)
{
  $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<i style='color: green;' class='fa fa-check'></i>";
}
```

So full code:

```
$isLogged = $_SESSION['id'] == $author_id;
$results = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $result)
{
  $foundCorrectAnswer = ($result['id'] == $AcceptedAnswerId);
  if($foundCorrectAnswer)
  {
    break;
  }
}

if($isLogged)
{
  $color = $foundCorrectAnswer ? 'green' : 'gray';
  $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<a href='#'><i style='color: {$color};' class='fa fa-check'></i></a>";
}
else if($foundCorrectAnswer)
{
  $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<i style='color: green;' class='fa fa-check'></i>";
}
```

Comment: What are `{` and `}` around `$acceptAnswerIcon` in that string?

Comment: Also your code is incomplete ...! What happens if "there is a accepted answer" and "current user isn't the author of question"? In this case I need to create a icon `<i>` out of `<a>`

Comment: What are { and } around $acceptAnswerIcon in that string? this simply escapes the variable. nothing special

Comment: In this case I need to create a icon `<i>` out of `<a>`. About this it's my fault I didnt' noticed that tiny difference, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Better your use Object Oriented PHP for better handling...

```
class Author{

    //funtion will return true if author
    function is_author(){

    }



    //function will return true if it is accepted.
    function is_accepted(){

    }


}


$author = new Author();
```

Now use this condition to reduce more if and else...

```
if ( $author->is_author() ) {
    //do something

    $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<a href='#'>
                                <i style='". if($author->is_accepted()) { ."color: green;".} else { ."color:gray;' class='fa fa-check'></i>
                             </a>";


} else {


    if($result['id'] == $AcceptedAnswerId){    // There isn accepted answer
        $AcceptAnswerIcon = "<i style='color: green;' class='fa fa-check'></i>";
    } else {                                   // There isn't accepted answer
        $AcceptAnswerIcon = null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Emm .. I don't know, defining a class and some methods just for a icon? `:-)`, Seems kinda expensive. But thanks for your approach ... +1

Comment: well.. manually its very difficult to reduce / simplify your if else while it it has many conditions... 

Alternatively you can use Switch by setting notation for each individual...

Answer (score 0):

### Remarks

- In your logic **if … elseif … else** the last **else** does not make sense since a user can only be logged or not.
- To make your code more compact, you could put strings (and other) elements used at different occasions, into variables or constants (defines).
  This has the effect that your code is smaller, and it also may be (?) faster.
  Here I created a template from the **<a href=…>** string with **{var}** tags that are replaced by variables at runtime.
- On the other side I would not recommend to make your code forcedly compact, when you risk to make it hard to understand.
- Below you find a more compact variant of your code.
  I used ternary conditions **$result = (condition) ? truevalue : falsevalue** which often makes the code more compact (but see above).

### Code Snippet

```
$results = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       // Fetching all answers
define ('template','<a href="#">'.PHP_EOL.'   <i style="color: {color};" class="fa fa-check"></i>'.PHP_EOL.'</a>');

foreach ($results as $result){
    $has_acceptedanswers = ($result['id'] == $AcceptedAnswerId);
    if ($_SESSION['id'] == $author_id){           // User is logged
        $template = template;
        $color = ($has_acceptedanswers) ? 'green' : 'gray';
    } else {                                      // User is not logged
        $template = ($has_acceptedanswers) ? template : false;
        $color = 'green';
    }
    $AcceptAnswerIcon = ($template === false) ? null : str_replace('{color}',$color,$template);

    //...
}
```

Comment: @Alex (not to say this is a bad answer @hherger) but the same problem of the html happens here.

Comment: May you please tell me why you used `PHP_EOL` ?

Comment: because the EOL (end of line) is different depending on the system you're using (linux, window, osx)